# Stop Chrome auto closing when no tabs are left

Tags: updates, chrome-for-android

I noticed a new behavior in Chrome after updating my device to Android 9. When I close every tab in Chrome, the app closes automatically.

This used not to be the case before I updated, even if there's no tabs remaining, Chrome will keep running on the tab switch screen. (Which has a "+" button in lower center which allows creating a new tab)

I'm used to closing the tab I'm using before opening a new tab, so this affects my normal usage. Are there any settings to change or anything to do to get back that function, **except** rolling back the Chrome version?

I'm using **Chrome 72.0.3626.105** on **Android 9 (Pie)** on the device **Huawei P Smart+ (INE-LX1)**.

Comment: The latest version I have is Chrome 72.x, maybe it's still not available in this region. When I get that update, I'll give the results. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I was on the version mentioned on the question, but updated after seeing your comment. :)

Comment: And the latest version also have this behavior...

Comment: Not for me, so maybe device issue of Huawei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution for removing this behavior. For me, turning off the toggle in *Settings >> Home Page* worked. It also removed another new behavior: showing Google home page when you start the browser. (it used to show the new tab page) It has a positive effect for me, but maybe not for anyone else, so be wary of that.